# Angularjs: Convert objects to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

This is my `data`:

```
 $scope.data = [ 
           {
            "top":"2",
            "status":"1",
            "name":"Anna",
           },
           {
            "top":"2",
            "status":"1",
            "name":"Jodie",
           },
           {
            "top":"2",
            "status":"1",
            "name":"susan",
           }
];
```

Now I want to convert the objects to arrays. When I run my program I get this following output in console log:

```
{
  "1":{
       "2":"3"
      }
}
```

But I need them to output as an array not object. Someone told me to use map function but I need to do them without using map function because it will cause a conflict in the process of my project. Is there any other way to do it without using map function?

The `1` in output means status object. `2` means top object and `3` means the number of students who's top is in 2.

This is the code I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/sjz5aLv1/

Any suggestions? TIA

Update:
I want the output which looks like this:

```
(
  [1] =>Array
       (
       [2] => 3
       )
)
```

Comment: Could you try to initialize the **details** as an array with **[]**.

Comment: Hi @Alexander the output what I want is just make the objects to array.

Comment: Hi @nerezo, I tried that earlier but I get undefined results.

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rrcLj13t/

Comment: Please give an example of what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I took below array for processing:

```
$scope.data = [
    { "top": "1", "status": "1", "name": "Anna" },
    { "top": "2", "status": "1", "name": "Jodie" },
    { "top": "2", "status": "1", "name": "Susan" },
    { "top": "3", "status": "1", "name": "Eddie" },
    { "top": "2", "status": "2", "name": "Megan" },
    { "top": "2", "status": "2", "name": "Frank" }
];
```

If I am not wrong you want a response like that:

```
[
    { 
        "1": [
                { "1": 1 },
                { "2": 2 },
                { "3": 1 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2": [
                { "2": 2 }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is a live demo in order to achieve above result: http://jsfiddle.net/nerezo/vz0dbdeq/

Comment: Hello Nerezo. The above code you gave was right. But what if I don't want them inside the object is it possible? I updated my question and I added the output. Thanks

Comment: @Yaoming your sample does not seem in JSON format, so your need still is not clear. If you want to keep the statuses in array based structure then you have to give indexes to the elements of that array and you can not give their statuses to them as indexes. And same rule applies to the top based array.